# Design pattern for asynchronous while loop

Tags: multithreading, macos, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I have a function that boils down to:

```
while(doWork)
{
  config = generateConfigurationForTesting();
  result = executeWork(config);
  doWork = isDone(result);
}
```

How can I rewrite this for efficient asynchronous execution, assuming all functions are thread safe, independent of previous iterations, and probably require more iterations than the maximum number of allowable threads ?

The problem here is we don't know how many iterations are required in advance so we can't make a `dispatch_group` or use `dispatch_apply`.

This is my first attempt, but it looks a bit ugly to me because of arbitrarily chosen values and sleeping;

```
int thread_count = 0;
bool doWork = true;
int max_threads = 20;  // arbitrarily chosen number

dispatch_queue_t queue =
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

while(doWork)
{
  if(thread_count < max_threads)
  {
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{ Config myconfig = generateConfigurationForTesting();
                             Result myresult = executeWork();
                             dispatch_async(queue, checkResult(myresult)); });
    thread_count++;
  }
  else
    usleep(100); // don't consume too much CPU
}

void checkResult(Result value)
{
  if(value == good) doWork = false;
  thread_count--;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it looks like `generateConfigurationForTesting` is some kind of randomization technique or otherwise a generator which can make a near-infinite number of configuration (hence your comment that you don't know ahead of time how many iterations you will need). With that as an assumption, you are basically stuck with the model that you've created, since your executor needs to be limited by some reasonable assumptions about the queue and you don't want to over-generate, as that would just extend the length of the run after you have succeeded in finding `value ==good` measurements.

I would suggest you consider using a queue (or `OSAtomicIncrement*` and `OSAtomicDecrement*`) to protect access to `thread_count` and `doWork`.  As it stands, the `thread_count` increment and decrement will happen in two different queues (main_queue for the main thread and the default queue for the background task) and thus could simultaneously increment and decrement the thread count.   This could lead to an undercount (which would cause more threads to be created than you expect) or an overcount (which would cause you to never complete your task).

Another option to making this look a little nicer would be to have `checkResult` add new elements into the queue if `value!=good`.   This way, you load up the initial elements of the queue using `dispatch_apply( 20, queue, ^{ ... })` and you don't need the `thread_count` at all. The first 20 will be added using `dispatch_apply` (or an amount that `dispatch_apply` feels is appropriate for your configuration) and then each time `checkResult` is called you can either set `doWork=false` or add another operation to `queue`.

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing a stochastic search algorithm; but it could also be the framework of a kind of genetic optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

`dispatch_apply()` works for this, just pass ncpu as the number of iterations (apply never uses more than ncpu worker threads) and keep each instance of your worker block running for as long as there is more work to do (i.e. loop back to `generateConfigurationForTesting()` unless `!doWork`).

Comment: What is ncpu ? Assuming ncpu is some large number; your solution gets GCD to run as many threads simultaneously as the system can handle and each thread runs as a loop. When the solution is found, use `doWork` to finish each thread and then all the threads in the `dispatch_apply()` get used up. Is that right ?

Comment: sorry for being unclear, ncpu is the number of cpus in the system, as obtained e.g. from `sysctlbyname("hw.ncpu",...)`. Yes, with this approach `dispatch_apply()` is essentially used as an efficient way to get all cpus to run your problem repeatedly until a solution is found.